# CLLocationManager not calling delegate

Tags: objective-c, macos, cllocationmanager

I am working on a Mac application. Following is a minimized test case. It seems like the CLLocationManager is not calling any delegate methods. Do you see anything wrong?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface Delegate : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL once;
@end

@implementation Delegate;
@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;
@synthesize once = _once;

- (void)start:(BOOL)once
{
    self.once = once;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Location: %@", self.locationManager.location);
    NSLog(@"authorizationStatus: %d", [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]);
    NSLog(@"locationServicesEnabled: %d", [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]);
    NSLog(@"significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable: %d", [CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable]);
    NSLog(@"headingAvailable: %d", [CLLocationManager headingAvailable]);
    NSLog(@"regionMonitoringAvailable: %d", [CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable]);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
{
    printf ( "%s\n", [newLocation.description UTF8String]);
    if (self.once) exit(0);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    printf ( "ERROR: %s\n", [[error localizedDescription] UTF8String]);
    exit(1);
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        BOOL once = (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "--once") == 0);
        Delegate *delegate = [[Delegate alloc] init];
        [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:once] waitUntilDone:NO];
        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop];
        [runLoop run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output is:

```
2013-03-25 20:24:28.342 CoreLocationCLI[75031:303] Location: (null)
2013-03-25 20:24:28.344 CoreLocationCLI[75031:303] authorizationStatus: 0
2013-03-25 20:24:28.345 CoreLocationCLI[75031:303] locationServicesEnabled: 1
2013-03-25 20:24:28.345 CoreLocationCLI[75031:303] significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable: 0
2013-03-25 20:24:28.346 CoreLocationCLI[75031:303] headingAvailable: 0
2013-03-25 20:24:28.346 CoreLocationCLI[75031:303] regionMonitoringAvailable: 1
```

Update: this is now implemented and working. Implementation for location printing at https://github.com/fulldecent/corelocationcli

Comment: Does your device/machine support Location Services?  Is it enabled?  Does the app have permission on the device?

Comment: How about `NSLog(@"%@", self.locationManager.location)` and the various properties of CLLocation?

Comment: It is supported, I have added the logging to show

Comment: Is this in the main thread?

Comment: Also try to see if your locationManager is getting deallocated after initializing it.

Comment: Do you have a non-wireless connection? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492439/cllocationmanager-does-not-work-for-non-wireless-connection

Comment: You might be using ARC. It deallocates the instance.

Comment: FYI This now works on 10.9 with zero changes. Full project for getting the GPS location on Mac saved to here: https://code.google.com/p/corelocationcli/

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `startUpdatingLocation`   check for  `+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled` value .

If its off turn on the location serviced in your system settings.

Comment: These are enabled. I have updated the question to log and show this.

Answer (score 0):

authorizationStatus: 0

It simply means that you have your authorization is oFF . PLease make sure it is ON.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status

Answer (score 0):

Put kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways OR
    kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse properties in info.plist